# React-Navigation: what does TabNavigator return?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm working on a ReactNative project and having trouble with react-navigation library.

I keep getting a blank screen after implementing TabNavigator from react-navigation.

Here's the code of Navigation.js:

```
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import PeopleList from './PeopleList';
import CompanyList from './CompanyList';
import AddPerson from './AddPerson';

const Navigation = TabNavigator({
    PeopleList: {
        screen: PeopleList
    },
    AddPerson: {
        screen: AddPerson
    },
    CompanyList: {
        screen: CompanyList
    },
}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'white',
        inactiveTintColor: '#80cbc4',
        swipeEnabled: true,
        showLabel: false,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: '#26a69a'
        },
    }
});

export default Navigation;
```

With the above code, I can only get a blank screen without any errors or exceptions.

If I simply return a "Text" tag, it gets rendered on the Simulator screen:

```
const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <Text>Test Navigation</Text>
    )
}
```

then I can see 'Test Navigation' on the screen.

I'm sure that the components imported in Navigation.js are all good. So I think the problem is on the TabNavigator function. I also compared the results in the React Native Debugger. When using TabNavigator, I got an 'Unknown' tag in my dom:
[image]

but if I simply use 'Text', there's no such tag called 'Unknown'.

BTW I'm using "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11".

Comment: Can you show how you're accessing the `Navigation` TabNavigator within `index.ios.js` or within whichever file you have the `AppRegistry.registerComponent('YourAppName', () => App)` at the end?

Comment: I'm importing Navigation in App.js, and index.ios.js uses App. Here's the code of these two files: https://codepen.io/mengqiao/pen/ZyvpGR?editors=0010

Comment: Are you attempting to build a website with `react-navigation`? They have an [example app](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/website/src/App.js) demonstrating that use case

Comment: I'm following a tutorial that uses react-native to build a crm. Thanks, I'll take a look at that example app

Comment: I found the problem. https://codepen.io/mengqiao/pen/ZyvpGR?editors=0010 In App.js, remove line65 and line67. Seems like you can't wrap Navigation with View.